# Adding external cordova plugin for audio recording in the Framework7 app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap, html-framework-7

I am new to Framework7. I am developing an app which has a requirement for recording audio and send it over the server like WhatsApp.
I am trying to add cordova-plugin-media (Link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-media). I added the plugin using

```
cordova plugin add [plugin-name]
```

and started using the plugin

```
var media = new Media(src, mediaSuccess, [mediaError], [mediaStatus]);
```

But it throws the error in the console saying
"Media is not defined"

I am writing this part of code in "deviceready" event of Framework7

My doubt is :

1] By just adding the plugin using cordova command does it get injected to the project or anything we want to do ?

2] If it needs to injected explicity How do I do it in Framework7 ?

I also tried importing the plugin using

```
cordova.require('path-to-plugin')
```

But it always says the plugin not found. By default where the require method looks for the plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

> 1] By just adding the plugin using cordova command does it get
>   injected to the project or anything we want to do ?

No, not in Framework7 project, because you are not using the cordova index page you will have to edit the main index page of the Framework7 app and include the cordova javascript file at the bottom before the `</body>` tag and before all other scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://your-project.com/www/cordova.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the repsonse, I have already added cordova.js in the head section. Is it correct ?

Comment: My friend you have 2 Cordova related js files, `cordova.js` in the www folder, and the `index.js` where the `deviceready` event is. And you also have 2 framework7 related js files, `framework7.min.js` and `my-app.js` or whatever you named it, which has your custom framework7 script, the four files should be included in this order: `cordova.js`, `framework7.min.js`, `my-app.js`, `index.js`, and it is better to move them to before closing the body tag `</body>`, I did this, and everything worked for me.